Trace formula for fermionic variables
I am using Bravyi's paper  "Lagrangian representation of fermionic linear optics" and one formula that stumbled me is the trace formula in Eq. (15) in the picture below:

I do not see how to arrive that the normalization factor. One way I could get it is as follows: consider one-mode example with $n=1$. By representing the Grassmann variables/Majorana operators as Pauli matrices, consider $X=Y=c_1 \equiv \sigma_x$, where $c_1$ is one of the Majorana operators. In this case, the LHS is $\text{Tr}(c_1^2) = 2$ from the anti-commutation relation. The RHS would need $(-2)$ prefactor because the Berezin integration has magnitude 1 (it is equal to $-1$).
However, suppose I do the "stupid" way and represent $c_1$ as direct sum of Pauli matrices,
\begin{align}
c_1 = \sigma_x\oplus\sigma_x\,,\qquad c_2 = \sigma_y\oplus\sigma_y\,.
\end{align}
This respects the anti-commutation relation, both square to identity but this time the identity matrix has dimension 4. Naïve trace on the LHS would have given $\text{Tr}(c_1^2)= 4\neq 2$, but the RHS of the trace formula only depends on the number of modes $n$. Am I missing something about the trace formula?

The trace here is (implicitly assumed to be) defined in terms of the Fermionic modes, i.e.
\begin{align}
    \operatorname{tr}(A) = \sum_x\langle x| A |x\rangle,
\end{align}
where $x$ in the sum ranges over the Fock basis states given on the second page of the paper.
When you represent the Majorana modes in terms of pairs of Pauli matrices you essentially double the size of your Hilbert space, so the sum defining the trace gets twice as many things to sum over.
Essentially the stuff in this paper only works when the Hilbert space is the span of the Fock basis states on page $2$.
